# Executable created using cx_freeze in Windows 7 crashes with errors about PyQt5 when run on other computers

Tags: python-3.x, cx-freeze, pyqt5

The executable runs perfectly on the system where I built it, but crashes with the following errors on the other systems I've tried...

```
Traceback(most recent call last):
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\cx_freeze-4.3.3-py3.4-win32.egg\cx_freeze\initscripts\Console.py", line 27, in <module>
File "monitor edi.py", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Python34\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 2214, in find and load
File "C:\Python34\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 2203, in find and load_unlocked
File "C:\Python34\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line ll91, in load unlocked
File "C:\Python34\lib\importlib\_bootstrap. py", line l l 6 l , in _load_backward_compatible
File "C:\Apps\cars\Code\cars utils.py", line 7, in <module>
File "C:\Python34\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 2261, in handle fromlist
File "C:\Python34\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 321, in call with frames_removed
File "C:\Python34\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 2214, in find and load
File "C:\Python34\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 2203, in find and load_unlocked
File "C:\Python34\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line ll91, in load unlocked
File "C:\Python34\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line ll61, in load_backward_compatible
File "ExtensionLoader_PyQt5_QtCore.py", line 22, in <module>
File "ExtensionLoader_PyQt5_QtCore.py", line 14, in  __bootstrap__
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I've read about some of the missing DLL issues like QWindows.DLL and libEGL.dll however it looks like cx_Freeze-4.3.3 has fixed those problems as those dlls are included in the build folder.

Built in 32 bit Python 3.4, with PyQt 5.3 and cx_Freeze 4.3.3

Here's the list of files in the build folder

```
icudt49.dll
icuin49.dll
icuuc49.dll
libEGL.dll
libGLESv2.dll
library.zip
monitor_edi.exe
msvcr100.dll
pyexpat.pyd
pyodbc.pyd
PyQt5.QtCore.pyd
PyQt5.QtGui.pyd
PyQt5.QtWidgets.pyd
python34.dll
pywintypes34.dll
Qt5Core.dll
Qt5Gui.dll
Qt5Widgets.dll
qwindows.dll
select.pyd
sip.pyd
tcl86t.dll
tk86t.dll
unicodedata.pyd
win32api.pyd
win32crypt.pyd
_bz2.pyd
_ctypes.pyd
_decimal.pyd
_hashlib.pyd
_lzma.pyd
_socket.pyd
_ssl.pyd
_tkinter.pyd
```

Any thoughts/suggestions/questions?

Comment: Try using [listdlls](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896656.aspx) on the unfrozen program to see which Qt DLLs weren't included.

Comment: [Dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) might also come in handy here.

Comment: I tried Dependency Walker which mentioned the python3.dll. However adding that dll did not change the error message at all.

Dependency walker's output included this message ****LoadLibraryExW("g:\share\exe.win32-3.4\PyQt5.QtCore.pyd", 0x00000000, LOAD_WITH_ALTERED_SEARCH_PATH) returned NULL. Error: The specified module could not be found (126).
**** That is the correct path to PyQt5.QtCore.pyd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to make sure that cx_Freeze is including the `atexit` module. I'm not really clear on why this is, but [the cx_Freeze PyQt example](https://bitbucket.org/reclosedev/cx_freeze/src/f3cacc2fd45a/samples/PyQt4/setup.py) includes this. If you're using the `cxfreeze` script you can make sure this happens with the `--include=atexit` option. If you're invoking cx_Freeze from your own setup.py script it might look something like this code adapted from my own work in progress:

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

base = None
if sys.platform == 'win32':
    base = 'Win32GUI'

setup(name = 'spamandeggs',
      version = '0.0.1',
      executables = [Executable('spamandeggs.pyw', base=base)],
      options = {'build_exe': {'includes': ['atexit']}})
```

If you're using the `PyQt5.Qsci` plugin, by the way, you'll also need to explicitly include `PyQt5.QtPrintSupport`. And I have found that I do still need to copy `libEGL.dll` in after cx_Freeze has done its stuff, but I'm also using cx_Freeze 4.3.3 so I'm not sure why that is.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error today, and finally found a solution for me after a whole day of searching. 
I copied msvcp100.dll, and everything works.

wft